# Exporting Referenced Types

Tags: typescript, reference, definition

I'd like to export a subset of globals from my definition file

**Example**

```js
// webrtc.globals.d.ts

/// <reference types="web" />

// Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'RTCIceCandidate'.
declare { RTCIceCandidate }
```

```js
// wrtc.d.ts

/// <reference types="web" />

// Cannot export 'RTCIceCandidate'. Only local declarations can be exported from a module.
declare module "webrtc" {
  export { RTCIceCandidate }
}
```

Thought process

- I want the typescript definitions for [wrtc])(https://www.npmjs.com/package/wrtc)
- They don't exist, but its just webrtc types anyway.
- Perhaps I can import the types from another defintion file and export them again in my declaration
- I can use [@types/webrtc](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/webrtc)
- It doesn't have [RTCIceCandidate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCIceCandidate)
- It is available in [@types/web](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/web)
- I don't want to have all the globals though. How do I restrict them?

For now I'm just going to allow all the globals in my applications but, if you are not aware, that is a bad idea since many of those globals simply do not exist.